# R for loops and if statements, can't save output as vector

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

Trying to replace output vector with string value of small, medium or large.

I am able to print out a string of 200 (1by1) vectors containing small/medium/large but not save that as a vector. What am I missing in the for loop?

```
output<- rep(NA, 200)  
size <- sample(1:5000, 200) 

myfun<- function(){ 
for (i in size) {   if (i < 300) {   print(output[i] <- "small")   }

else if (i >= 300 & i<3000) {   print(output[i] <- "medium") } 

else if (i>= 3000) {   print(output[i]<- "large")   } } } 

output<- myfun()
```

Comment: A loop isn't necessary for this. See the `cut` function.

Comment: A loop isn't necessary for this. See the `ifelse` function.

Comment: `output = ifelse(size < 300, "small", ifelse(size < 3000, "medium", "large"))`

Comment: `output = as.character(cut(size, breaks = c(0, 300, 3000, Inf), labels = c("small", "medium", "large")))`